How can i read a username and password from a .txt file using tkinter
I am reletively new to python and was trying to make a basic login page using tkinter and reading and writing data in a text file, so to have multiple 'accounts'. I was able to write the data in the format "a,b \n", and i am trying to then read the data as a username and password to verify a login, again working with multiple accounts.
This is my program:
import tkinter as tk

from ctypes import windll

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Log-in Page")
root.configure(background = "#e7d1ff")
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

def login_data():
    for file in open("saveData.txt", "r").readlines():
        login = file.split()
    print(login)

root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(False, False)

root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight = 3)

userLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Username:", font="arial 22 bold", bg = "#e7d1ff")
userLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=10)

userEntry = tk.Entry(root, font="helvetica 22")
userEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx=5, pady=10)

passLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Password:", font="arial 22 bold", bg = "#e7d1ff")
passLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=10)

passEntry = tk.Entry(root, font="helvetica 22", show="*")
passEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx=5, pady=10)

def test_function():
    file = open("saveData.txt", "a")
    user_info = str(userEntry.get() + "," + str(passEntry.get() + "\n"))
    file.write(user_info)
    file.close()

btnLogin = tk.Button(root, text="Login", font="arial 16 bold", command = test_function)
btnLogin.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)

btnTest = tk.Button(root, text="Test", font="arial 16 bold", command = login_data)
your textbtnTest.place (relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()

I am stuck on the login_data function. How can i make this work?

What do you mean by stuck on the login_data function? Please explain what is not working, or working in an incorrect way.

Why is the Login button writing to the file? Shouldn't it read the file, and check whether the username and password are in there?

Typo error your textbtnTest.place (relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER), on line 43

Inside of your 'login_data()' function, when using 'split()' it will split the data by whitespace. To split the data by a comma, use '.split(',')'. You also may find it more useful to use a dictionary rather than just a variable storing usernames and passwords in an unstructured format.
This will work better for you given your situation:
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll

windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Log-in Page")
root.configure(background="#e7d1ff")
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(False, False)


def save_data():
    with open("saveData.txt", "a") as file:
        user_info = f"{userEntry.get()},{passEntry.get()}\n"
        file.write(user_info)

def login_data(): # Edited this function
    login_dict = {} # Use a dictionary instead.
    
    with open("saveData.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            line = line.strip()  
            if line:  # Skip empty lines if any are found
                
                username, password = line.split(',') #Splits by comma now, not spaces.
                login_dict[username] = password

    entered_username = userEntry.get()
    entered_password = passEntry.get()

    # Double checks username or password was already saved.
    if entered_username in login_dict and login_dict[entered_username] == entered_password:
        print("Login Successful!")
    else:
        print("Invalid username or password.")

userLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Username:", font="arial 22 bold", bg="#e7d1ff")
userLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=10)

userEntry = tk.Entry(root, font="helvetica 22")
userEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

passLabel = tk.Label(root, text="Password:", font="arial 22 bold", bg="#e7d1ff")
passLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E, padx=5, pady=10)

passEntry = tk.Entry(root, font="helvetica 22", show="*")
passEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)

btnLogin = tk.Button(root, text="Login", font="arial 16 bold", command=login_data)
btnLogin.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.4, anchor=tk.CENTER)

btnSave = tk.Button(root, text="Save", font="arial 16 bold", command=save_data)
btnSave.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()

